# Can I prevent automatic generation of ROWID in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, rowid

As far as I know, SQLite generates ROWID automatically. (regardless to it's AUTOINCREMENT or now) But I want to supply ROWID explicitly, and raise an error if ROWID is not specified on INSERT. Instead of automatic generation.

Is this possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own AUTOINCREMENT field (f.e "id"). If you define an AUTOINCREMENT Field you can SELECT this via "Fieldname (id?)" or the keyword "rowid".